# Symfony: How to load custom bundle config from file?

Tags: php, symfony

I am using `Symfony 3.4`. How can I add a custom config file to a custom bundle which should hold a list of names and regular expressions? For example:

```
// Config file content = list of names and regular expressions
NameA
NameB
Name[cC]+
Some\w+Other(Name|Pattern)
...


// Symfony controller
$patterns = $this->getPatternConfigFromFileSomehow(...);
```

In in the Symfony docs I found information on adding custom config to the `.yml` files in the `app/config` or `MyBundle/Resources/config` dirs. However, this is not about a small set of well defined parameters (e.g. `mailaddress: xyz`) but list of any number of entries.

Additionally the config should only be loaded if its actually used and not every time the kernel or a services is created.

Of course I could simply use `file_get_contents` or any similar PHP method to load any file, however this seems to be quite hacky and not the *"Symfony way"*...

So, what is the *"correct"* way of doing this?

**EDIT:**

yml files are great to configure **parameters**, but this is **not** about parameters (= key + value) but a list of file names and regular expressions. This list does **not** have a defined length and the entries do **not** have defined names. Thus .yml is not the right solution here, is it?

Additionally config files which are added using the ConfigTreeBuilder are loaded when the kernel is loaded, aren't they? I am looking for a lazy solution which loads the list only when needed.

Comment: I'm not sure to fully understand your problem, but can't you use yaml `imports` ?
e.g. : 
`imports:
    - { resource: '%kernel.project_dir%/YourBundle/Resources/config.yaml' }`

Comment: This would for `key: value` style parameters which is not the case here. Please look at my edit.

Comment: file_get_contents is probably what you want for your specific requirement.  The term 'config' in your title is probably not the best word to use.  Seems like you are loading data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your yml file in any config directory (app/config,config,Resources/config) that is loaded. How you name the file does not 'really' matter. What matter is that your root node in this yml is the root node you define in 
**/your-bundle/src/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php**

if you defined it like this :

```
public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
{
    $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder('your_root_node' );
    $treeBuilder->getRootNode()... 

    // with use of array prototypes... 

    $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder('your_root_node');
    $rootNode = $treeBuilder->getRootNode();

    $rootNode
        ->children()
            ->arrayNode('fields')
                ->arrayPrototype()
                    ->children()
                        ->enumNode('type')
                            ->values(['iris','iri','entity','entities','datetime','string','integer','boolean','custom_class'])
                            ->defaultNull()
                        ->end()
                        ->enumNode('type_out')
                            ->values(['iris','iri','entity','entities','datetime','string','integer','boolean','custom_class'])
                            ->defaultNull()
                        ->end()
                        ->scalarNode('entity')->defaultNull()->end()
                        ->scalarNode('customClass')->defaultNull()->end()
                        ->arrayNode('parameters')
                            ->useAttributeAsKey('name')
                            ->scalarPrototype()->end()
                        ->end()
                        ->booleanNode('nullable')->defaultFalse()->end()
                    ->end()
                ->end()
            ->end()
        ->end()
    ;

    ...
}
```

Then you should have a yml file starting like this:

```
your_root_node:
    my_parameter:
    my_other_parameter:
        and_so_on:
```

Also, config file with definition don't have to be loaded with kernel and can be loaded 'lazily' in a service like this:

```
    use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Builder\TreeBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\ConfigurationInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Processor;
class SchemaConfiguration implements ConfigurationInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
        $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('schema');
        $rootNode
            ... // Tree definition
            ->end()
        ;
        return $treeBuilder;
    }
    /**
     * @param $schemaConfig
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getSchemaFromYaml($schemaConfig){
        $configuration = new SchemaConfiguration();
        $processor = new Processor();
        $processed = $processor->processConfiguration($configuration, $schemaConfig);
        $schema = $processed['fields'];
        return $schema ;
    }


}
```

Comment: This would for `key: value` style parameters which is not the case here. Please look at my edit.

Comment: I edited my answer, added example of use of array prototype to defines list of values or key/values

Comment: Here we go, that's what you're looking for I think